# Read and write empty string "" vs NULL in Spark 2.0.1

Tags: csv, apache-spark

`CSVFileFormat` seems to read and write empty values as null for string columns. I have searched around but have been unable to find clear information about this, so I put together a simple test.

```
val df = session.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (0, "a"),
    (1, "b"),
    (2, "c"),
    (3, ""),
    (4, null)
))  

df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv") 
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("nullValue", "unknown")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false")
    .save(s"$path/test")
```

This outputs:

```
0,a
1,b
2,c
3,unknown
4,unknown
```

So, it appears to be treating both empty strings and `null` values as `null`. The same thing happens when reading a CSV file with empty quoted strings and nulls. Is there currently any way to treat these differently?

Comment: It seems they've explicitly set empty string to null in https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14118. And there is an open PR to provide for empty string vs null values - https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/12904.

Comment: can't you simply replace the `null` and empties with different values before writing and after reading ? I think it's also mentioned in one of the links you posted.

Comment: @Chitral Verma Sure, this is possible, but not always feasible depending on the source of the file, or the destination. It also adds an additional transformation step to every read and write that I think should not be necessary.

Comment: whenever those changes get merged, the transformation overhead with still be there. It'll just be abstract though. source and destination don't really matter as this problem only pertains to CSVFileFormat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A mere two and a half years later, empty strings are no longer considered equal to `null` values thanks to [Spark 2.4.0](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-0.html)!  See [this commit for a bit of detail](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/7a2d4895c75d4c232c377876b61c05a083eab3c8#diff-eb708fbebdf6d20d1ab1b109f5f2cd56) on functionality.  Your code will behave as expected under 2.4.0+:

```
val df = session.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (0, "a"),
    (1, "b"),
    (2, "c"),
    (3, ""),
    (4, null)
))  

df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv") 
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("nullValue", "unknown")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false")
    .save(s"$path/test")
```

Results in:

```
0,a
1,b
2,c
3,
4,unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree this behavior is a great improvement but BE WARNED if you use Sqoop to export CSV files in production that are created with Spark and you update without changing

```
.option("nullValue", "null")
```

then your Sqoop Export will fail, and it will likely throw you an error that provides utterly no insight into the root cause of this. 100% a Sqoop problem, and if at all possible I highly urge everyone to take advantage of Spark JDBC support for exports, but be warned and aware. Lots of enterprises out there still rely on Sqoop heavily.